# Triggering events during a swipe android

Tags: android, animation, touch, frame, swipe

I have a set of images to be displayed on an imageview to create an animation effect.

The idea is that as the user swipes right ,the the images displayed on the imageview should change in a particular order.
For a left swipe,there needs to have another order for the images displayed on the screen.

As the user swipes the screen,the images should change and once he takes his hand off the screen,the imageview should not change images and should stop at the current image.

How can I achieve this?
I cant think of a way to change the images as the user is swiping and stopping as he releases his hand.
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Try using a `SimpleOnGestureListener` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float) as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10706822/3071356

Comment: I know about that.But the onFling code is invoked only after the swipe is performed and ended.But I need to chenge imags during swipe and end it after the completion of swipe